# How to change the background color depending on the text view

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview

I would like to change the background color depending on the bluetooth status. When the button is clicked, the text (Bluetooth on) appears in the text view. After the second press of the same button, the text (Bluetooth Off) appears and I wanted to change the background color depending on the text.
`

```
switch (Tv.getText().toString()){
    case "Bluetooth ON":
        layoutleft.setBackgroundResource(R.color.Green);
        break;

    case "Bluetooth OFF":
        layoutleft.setBackgroundResource(R.color.Red);
        break;


}
```

`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:layout_height="413dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ListView"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="277dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="277dp"

    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
```

I tried to do it like this: (code ) seems to work but doesn't change dynamically until after turning the screen off and on.

Comment: setBackgroundResource(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.grey))

Fetch resource like this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you already try using a different method on the TextView?

There are lost of different methods for just the background, such as `Tv.setBackgroundColor(R.color.Green);`

`Tv.setBackgroundResource(R.color.Green)` just looks into the drawable folder for a Resource called whatever you've named it :).

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: unfortunately didnt help

Comment: What exactly is "Tv"? Is it a variable? Could you provide more of your code?

Comment: Tv - Text View ( My variable)

Comment: Can you provide more of your code..? How did you declare the variable? Using ```textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);``` works just fine for me. Did you declare ```R.color.Green``` correctly? (If you don't know what I'm talking about: The R.colors variable references this file "res/values/colors.xml". If nothing of the above mentioned works for you. You can also just use ```Color.parseColor(R.colors.GREEN)```. That might work too.

Answer (score 0):

```
switch (Tv.getText().toString()){
  case "Bluetooth ON":
      layoutleft.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#5CE058"));
      break;

  case "Bluetooth OFF":
      layoutleft.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFF6A5"));
      break;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately didnt help

Comment: can you share the xml code of  layoutleft

Comment: I posted xml code

Comment: Which view casted as "layoutleft"   ?  there is no view with id "layoutleft"

Comment: Is the switch case write inside  onCLickListner ?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of different methods for just the background, try following

```
textView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.green)
```